# (Powershell) Read and change JSON value to a date

Tags: json, powershell

I'm trying to write a powershell script that could read a JSON, its extension is .pros, then change the project name from "test" to "test 12/12 13:24" or something similar. So far I was able to read it, but then I can't get to the project_name field.

my code:

```
$pros = Get-ChildItem -Path $house -Recurse -Include *.pros
$time = Get-Date -Format 'u'
$pog = Get-Content $pros -raw | ConvertFrom-Json    
$pog.update | $_.project_name=$time
$pog | ConvertTo-Json -depth 32| set-content $pros
Write-Output $time
```

The .pros:

```
{
    "py/object":  "pros.conductor.project.Project",
    "py/state":  {
                     "project_name":  "Marcos_Yuck_new",
                     "target":  "v5",
                     "templates":  {
                                       "kernel":  {
                                                      "location":  "/home/dragon/.config/pros/templates/kernel@3.5.3",
                                                      "metadata":  {
```

Comment: `$pog.'py/state'.project_name = "test ${time}"`

Comment: Thanks! So, is there a difference between ' and " because I think I tried with " and it didn't like it?

Comment: `"` are for _expandable_ string literals - that is, simple variable references (like `${time}`) and explicit subexpressions will be evaluated and substituted in the final string value. So `'py/state'` and `"py/state"` both describe the same string value (and either will work here), but `'test ${time}'` and `"test ${time}"` do _not_ describe the same string value.